# Meteor image doesn't show up on every pages

Tags: meteor

I created this website : pictionary6470.meteor.com using meteor.
The image logo only shows up on home page but not on game page (after you log in and start to continue a game).

There are two pages which I created using routers. I have the image included in my template, and included the template using the same code on both pages.

in html:

```
<body>
{{> nav}}
</body>
```

I put the nav template in the home.html, and refer to it in the game.html.

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="/" class="brand-logo"><img src="icon.png" height="50" width="350"/></a>

  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right side-nav">
    <li>{{>loginButtons}}</li>
    {{#if currentUser}} 

    {{/if}}
  </ul>

</div>
```

Another problem im having is that when it router to different pages, it flash once then get to the destination page. Does any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

First add iron router package.

```
meteor add iron:router
```

Second lets use the `{{> yield}}`, helper on the new layout template

```
 <template name="layout">
    <a href="/" class="brand-logo"><img src="icon.png" height="50" width="350"/></a>
   <div>
      {{> yield}}
   </div>
    </template>
```

now on a new file inside `lib/routes.js` add the new code.

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'load',
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

For that flash thing lets add a loadingTemplate

first add `meteor add sacha:spin`

and create a new template like this

```
<template name="load">
{{> spinner}}
</template>
```

You need to understand that we all calling all the  to the layout template, and we place it inside the {{> yield}} helper. so any content outside the yield helper will be available on all webpage.

For more about `{{>yield}}` and how it works take a look [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fes.discovermeteor.com%2Fchapters%2Frouting%2F&edit-text=&act=url)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`<img src="/icon.png" height="50" width="350"/>`